# React - updating state to add/remove active class from tab navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tab navigation at the top of my page, and I want to add an 'active' class to the tab when it's clicked and make sure it's not on any of the other tabs.

So far what I have adds the 'active' class to the first tab, but doesn't update if you click on any of the other tabs. So the first tab is always the active tab regardless of what you click on.

```
import React from 'react'
import { string } from 'prop-types'

class TabNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentTab: ''
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.createTabItems = this.createTabItems.bind(this)
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.navItems !== this.props.navItems
  }

  handleClick (currentTab) {
    this.setState({
      currentTab: currentTab
    })
    this.createTabItems()
  }

  createTabItems () {
    const { navItems = false } = this.props
    if (!navItems) return false
    const splitItems = navItems.split(',')
    if (!splitItems.length) return false
    return splitItems.map((item, currentTab) => {
      const items = item.split('_')
      if (items.length !== 3) return null
      const itemLink = items[1]
      return (
        <li key={currentTab} className={this.state.currentTab == currentTab ? 'side-nav-tab active' : 'side-nav-tab'} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, currentTab)}>
            <a href={itemLink}>
              <p>{ items[0] }</p>
            </a>
        </li>
      )
    })
  }

  render () {
    const tabItems = this.createTabItems()
    if (!tabItems) return null
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id='tabNavigation'>
          {tabItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TabNav.propTypes = {
  navItems: string.isRequired
}

export default TabNav
```

I have also tried calling this.createTabItems asynchronously in setState to try and force an update but that didn't work:

```
 handleClick (currentTab) {
    this.setState({
      currentTab: currentTab
    }, () => this.createTabItems)
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but some whitespace in `createTabItems` would go a long way to aiding readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `shouldComponentUpdate` is causing the issue. Can you try removing it? Also, you don't need to call `this.createTabItems` in your `handleClick()`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a mindset shift is required here to think more declaratively, you don't need to tell React when you want to create the tabs, it will determine this itself from the render method and the data that's passed to it.

I've removed your componentShouldUpdate function because React will already do the comparison of those props for you. I've also tracked the selected item by index because it simplifies the logic in my mind.

Try something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { string } from 'prop-types';

class TabNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick = index => {
    this.setState({
      selectedIndex: index
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { navItems = [] } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul id="tabNavigation">
          {navItems.map((navItem, index) => {
            if (navItem.length !== 3) return;

            const [text, link] = navItem;

            return (
              <li
                className={
                  this.state.selectedIndex === index
                    ? 'side-nav-tab active'
                    : 'side-nav-tab'
                }
                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, index)}
              >
                <a href={link}>
                  <p>{text}</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TabNav.propTypes = {
  navItems: string.isRequired
};

export default TabNav;
```

There are a couple other changes in there, like destructuring from the array rather than using indexes so it's clearer what the properties you're pulling out of a navItem array are.

I also used a fat arrow function for the handleClick function because it means you don't have to bind to `this` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You got two problems, first the way you are using `this` in your function and secondly your `shouldUpdateComponent`, just like the other mentioned before me. If you want to reference your class using `this` you need to use arrow functions. remember that the ES6 arrow function uses **lexical scoping** which means that `this` references the code that contains the function. I made the changes in the code below with a working example.

```js
class TabNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentTab: ''
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.createTabItems = this.createTabItems.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick (currentTab) {
    this.setState({
      currentTab: currentTab
    })
  }

  createTabItems = () => {
    const { navItems = false } = this.props
    if (!navItems) return false
   
    const splitItems = navItems.split(',')
    if (!splitItems.length) return false
    return splitItems.map((item, currentTab) => {
      const items = item.split('_')
      if (items.length !== 3) return null
      const itemLink = items[1]
      return (
        <li key={currentTab} className={this.state.currentTab == currentTab ? 'side-nav-tab active' : 'side-nav-tab'} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, currentTab)}>
            <a href={itemLink}>
              <p>{ items[0] }</p>
            </a>
        </li>
      )
    })
  }

  render () {
    const tabItems = this.createTabItems()
    if (!tabItems) return null
    return (
      <div>
        <ul id='tabNavigation'>
          {tabItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <TabNav navItems={'Test1_#_Test1,Test2_#_Test2'} />)
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Nav />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

.

Comment: That's not strictly true, you don't _have_ to use fat arrow functions to use `this`, it's just a time saver. The binding in the constructor takes care of that if you don't want to use a fat arrow function.